# Running MSBuild script on development machine

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, continuous-integration

I have an MSBuild script which performs a lot of tasks, as it is run on our build server.  I want the script to be run each time a developer builds from Visual Studio on their local development machine, so that

a) the build process they are runnning locally is the same as that run by the build server so any problems in the build can be identified immediately by the developer 
b) many of the operations of the build script are run on local builds, for example running of unit tests, generation of code coverage reports etc

How is this possible in Visual Studio (2008)?  Note I am running a single solution product with multiple projects.

Comment: Are you sure you want developers running this script *each* time they build? Sounds to me a job for the build runner, e.g.: TeamCity, CC.NET, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute that script in the Pre/PostBuildEvent or in the Before/AfterBuild targets.

Answer (score 0):

Hook a custom MSBuild shell command into the Tools menu as an external tool. The command pointing to the MSBuild executable and the arguments list being something like:

`$(SolutionDir)\main.msbuild /t:Build /p:Configuration=Local`

You can then add this as a specific build command button to any of the toolbars. Granted, it does not replace the existing baked in Build command from VS.NET, but it allows an easy way for the developer to build using MSBuild without leaving their IDE.